# Installing Cryptography on an Apple Silicon M1 Mac

Tags: python-cryptography, apple-silicon, apple-m1

Help! I'm trying to install cryptography on my m1. I know I can run terminal in rosetta mode, but I'm wondering if there is a way not to do that.

Output:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/tmpl4sga84k
         cwd: /private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-install-jko4b562/cryptography_7b1bbc9ece2f481a8e8e9ea03b1a0030
    Complete output (55 lines):
    
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
        If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
        successfully install cryptography:
        1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
           users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
        2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
           instructions for your platform.
        3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
           https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 44, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 432, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self, {
      File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 292, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 708, in finalize_options
        ep(self)
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 715, in _finalize_setup_keywords
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 219, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "src/_cffi_src/build_openssl.py", line 77, in <module>
        ffi = build_ffi_for_binding(
      File "src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 54, in build_ffi_for_binding
        ffi = build_ffi(
      File "src/_cffi_src/utils.py", line 74, in build_ffi
        ffi = FFI()
      File "/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 48, in __init__
        import _cffi_backend as backend
    ImportError: dlopen(/private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure
      Referenced from: /private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so
      Expected in: flat namespace
     in /private/var/folders/hj/5zfkv68d7lqgrfqt046bn23c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-9bqzge_f/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

I've tried to build and run like their instructions say in that code block to the same error. I've looked around and nobody has seemingly found the fix yet, but those things are two months old usually. What am I missing?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This issue is due to a mismatch between the libffi header version and the version of libffi the dynamic linker finds. In general it appears users encountering this problem have homebrew libffi installed and have a Python built against that in some fashion.

When this happens `cffi` (a `cryptography` dependency) compiles, but fails at runtime raising this error. This should be fixable by passing the right path as a linker argument. To reinstall `cffi` you should `pip uninstall cffi` followed by

`LDFLAGS=-L$(brew --prefix libffi)/lib CFLAGS=-I$(brew --prefix libffi)/include pip install cffi --no-binary :all:`

This is an ugly workaround, but will get you past this hurdle for now.

**Update**: I've uploaded arm64 wheels for macOS so the below compilation is no longer required if your `pip` is up-to-date. However, if, for some reason you wish to compile it yourself:

`LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include" pip install cryptography`

**Update 2023**: As of 2023 there are wheels for cffi and cryptography for Apple Silicon. If you are still seeing this type of error, there are a few likely culprits:

1. Your `pip` is out of date. Update to latest! You can (and should) do all of this in a virtual environment.
2. You are attempting to install an older version of `cryptography`. Any version >= 3.4.6 has an apple silicon wheel (either `arm64` or `universal2`), but we only support the latest release so always update.
3. You are attempting to install an older version of `cffi`. `cffi` cannot use `abi3` so new wheels must be uploaded for each major Python release. If you're attempting to run an older `cffi` on a newer Python then a wheel may not be available and you'll need to compile.

Comment: Thanks, found this elsewhere but it is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: When I run `pip uninstall cffi` it just tells me that package isn't installed. But I'm getting the exact error above.

Comment: Update not working yet even though I have up to date pip installed. Still the first workaround worked. Thankyou

Comment: The updated info is for the `cryptography` package, which has substantially more build requirements.  The primary instructions are for working around `cffi` problems, which (as of June 2021) does not ship a macOS arm64 wheel. Once you have that then the `cryptography` wheel will work and simplify your installation.

Comment: The cryptography I have on my M1 Mac's built in python doesn't work right.  For example fabric won't work with it.  I was able to get a python2 for arm from the Nix package manager (the only place I could find packages for python2 for the M1 Macs) and from there I installed a cryptography that works.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68293059/mac-os-11-4-big-sur-fixing-python-cryptography-package-in-system-library-fram/68309199

Comment: See https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-macos

Comment: This can fix a lot of cffi dependency libraries installation issues.

Comment: Thank you! I was breaking my head to resolve this issue, this command saved me hours LDFLAGS=-L$(brew --prefix libffi)/lib CFLAGS=-I$(brew --prefix libffi)/include pip install cffi --no-binary :all:

I am using Mac M2 machine

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Macbook Pro M1 2020 model and faced the same issue. The issue was only with my cffi and pip versions maybe. Because these 4 steps helped me -

1. Uninstalling old cffi `pip uninstall cffi`
2. Upgrading pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
3. Reinstalling cffi `pip install cffi`
4. Intalling cryptography `pip install cryptography`

Answer (score 11):

A little late to the party, but the solutions above didn't work for me. Paul got me on the right track, but my problem was that pyenv used the mac libffi for its build and cffi used the homebrew version. I read this somewhere, can't claim this unique insight.

My solution was to ensure that my python (3.8.13) was built by pyenv using the homebrew libffi by ensuring correct headers libraries and package config:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib -L$(brew --prefix libffi)/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include -I$(brew --prefix libffi)/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix libffi)/lib/pkgconfig"
```

rebuilding python...

```
pyenv uninstall 3.8.13
pyenv install 3.8.13
```

killing the pip cache

```
pip cache purge
```

and, finally, reinstalling my dependencies using pipenv

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv sync --dev
```

After these steps, I was free from the dreaded

```
ImportError: dlopen(/private/var/folders/k7/z3mq67_532bdr_rcm2grml240000gn/T/pip-build-env-apk5b25z/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ffi_prep_closure'
```

Comment: Thanks for the type, the CFLAGS and PKGCONFIG in this answer did the trick

Comment: Wish I could give a beer for that answer, @Matt. Most of other answers I was seeing around this issue weren't going to work for me, and I had my suspicions that this was the cause, but didn't realize that pyenv would rebuild the *old* Python version I needed with the right linked libraries in this manner. Thank you!

Comment: I virtually accept that beer @ewall

Answer (score 6):

Probably, you'll have a problem with more packages and each has it's own solution for Apple Silicon, it's exhausting.

I came to final solution: using x86_x64 Homebrew which installs x86 packages, including Python. Thus, all your requirements are installing as on the x86_x64 macs and there are no more problems with the compilation errors and so on.

Instructions:

1. Run iTerm2 (or default Terminal app) under Rosetta 2 (right click on the app icon -> `Get info` -> `Open using rosetta`).
2. Install homebrew as usual `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` or you can get this link from https://brew.sh/ for security reasons (never copy curl commands from stackoverflow without double-checking).
3. Add an alias in your `~/.zshrc` (if you're using ZSH) or `~/.bash_profile` (if you're bash user): `alias brew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'`.
4. Turn off `Open using rosetta` in iTerm2 `Get info`.

Now, every time you'll print `brew` in terminal apps you'll run x86_x64 Homebrew. And when you install any package from `brew`, it'll work under Rosetta 2 automatically.

Comment: Haven't gotten to this yet, but THANK YOU! This is crazy. I bought a MacMini M1 with the full intention of using it as a build server. Oye Vie! What a mess.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer here worked like a charm! @paveldroo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66422219/8524011)

As an extension to the answer above, I went ahead and saved the alias in step 3 as `alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'` at `~/.zshrc`

This means when I install anything with `brew` command, it gets installed for M1 architecture, and when I install with `ibrew` command it gets installed for -x86_64 architecture.

As a consequence, I installed two instances of python3 at my system one at `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` using `brew` and the other at `/usr/local/bin/python3` using `ibrew`

The two versions adds some flexibility on creating the project virtual environments as needed. For example you could create virtual environments using:

1. `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv venv` for -x86_64 architecture
2. `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 -m venv venv` for M1 architecture

Answer (score 3):

I have uninstalled older version of `cffi` and `cryptography`,

```
pip uninstall cffi
pip uninstall cryptography
```

and updated the `requirements.txt` file from exact versions to updated versions

```
# requirements.txt

cffi>=1.15.1 
cryptography>=38.0.1
```

(version number can be different).
This resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to previously install cffi, until I discovered an unrelated issue. I was at this for about two days, until I found this command:

```sh
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Magically, everything started working for me. It came from an issue between Python and Pip coming from different sources.

Answer stolen from this question: [using pip3: module "importlib._bootstrap" has no attribute "SourceFileLoader"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader)

Edit: This may be a courtesy of the above poster, so could be unrelated. If so, thank you anonymous human!

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my issue by using the `intel64` version of python. So I installed python using the *macOS 64-bit universal2 installer* from [python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/).

Then I just needed to create the virtual env using e.g: `python3.11-intel64` file from `/usr/local/bin/` and installed all packages with that version:

```
$ venv/bin/python-intel64 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And everything started to work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably incompatibility issue, for me I resolved it by installing a stable version from **cryptography**:

1. `pip uninstall cryptography`
2. `pip install cryptography==3.4.8`