# Issue with installation bcrypt for Python 3.7.10 env on Mac M1 Pro

Tags: python, bcrypt, apple-m1, python-cffi

For current project need to set up environment with Python 3.7 on Mac with M1 Pro.
During installation of bcrypt requirement faced following error:

```
  import _cffi_backend as backend
  ImportError: dlopen(/private/var/folders/f5/q5mrcmbn5rg9359pq56wnd6c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-098zmvix/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ffi_prep_closure'
```

Tried to reinstall cffi, like here mentioned ([Installing Cryptography on an Apple Silicon M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035003/installing-cryptography-on-an-apple-silicon-m1-mac)), but it didn't help

Do you have any ideas?